# Delete messages in a specific channel using channel id

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command for my discord bot that sends embeds in different channels(using the id) and deletes the message that was sent before. I've googled a lot and I still can't find a working solution on how to delete messages in a specific channel using the channel ID. I only need 1 message to be deleted if that's easier but I don't know.

This is my  code:

```
client.channels.cache.get('channelid').messages.fetch().then(message => message.delete())
client.channels.cache.get('channelid').send({ embeds: [FAQEmbed] }); // sends FAQ Embed
```

I replaced the id with `channelid` in case of anything. The embed works and it sends, but the message before doesn't get deleted.

Comment: I'm not sure what message you want to delete. The one with the command?

Comment: I want to delete the message that I send yes with the embed. But I want to delete the message that was sent before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your code correct, but if you want to delete the message when bot replied. 
use `message.channel.id` and `message.id` to return message and channel id
example:

```js
client.channels.cache.get(message.channel.id).messages.fetch(message.id).then(message => message.delete())
```

hope this help you, but you need to defined the `client` as well